# Unable to locate ros-noetic-desktop-full

Tags: installation, ros-noetic, ros-package-path, apt

I need ros-noetic-desktop-full for my job and i'm totally unable to make apt locate this package.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04.6 as needed.

I tried following the official documentation

1. Setup source list

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

2. Setup keys

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

3. Update

```sh
sudo apt update  

Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/redislabs/redis/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:3 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]            
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease                       
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rock-core/qt4/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Get:7 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:8 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]  
Get:9 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]   
Hit:4 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Get:10 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [274 kB]
Get:11 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [414 kB]
Get:12 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Get:13 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,012 B]
Get:14 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]
Get:15 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.8 kB]
Get:16 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [96.8 kB]
Get:17 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
```

4. Install

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
  
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

Comment: What does `apt-cache search ros-noetic` show?  (cut and paste some of the text from the terminal, don't take text screenshots)

Comment: Sorry, i just updated the formating and added `apt-cache search ros-noetic` output

Comment: What is the output of apt get update? Also what is 'apt-cache policy' for one on the packages that does list in noetic? I'd there anything else ROS related in you apt sources?

Comment: I updated the question with apt update output, there are a couple of apt source listed. The apt-cache policy shot a bunch of different Focal versions

Comment: I just delete all ros-noetic packages and i'm still unable to install ros-noetic-desktop-full